# Identity Server 4 - using self-signed RSA key with AddDeveloperSigningCredential in non-Development environments

Tags: asp.net-core, rsa, identityserver4, development-environment, production-environment

I am using Identity Server 4 (.Net Core 2.2) in all of our environments (Development, Test, Production) and we have a Startup as follows

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"))
            .AddConfigurationStore(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDB"))
            .AddOperationalStore(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDB"))
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

- this uses our temporary RSA key file generated within our Debug/Development environment (tempkey.rsa).

This is currently functioning - users are authenticated and claims processed

I realize that this is not recommended in any other environment than locally/Development however we are about to migrate from ADFS-3 to ADFS-4 which will change the architecture and hence we will no longer have a need for the above code (and potentially no need for our instance of Identity Server 4)

I also realize that there are limitations in the solution regarding

- single/multiple instances (the same RSA key would need to be in sync across multiple instances if that were the case).
- there is also a concern with the visibility of tempkey.rsa over the Internet - the folder it is in isn't served over the Internet

I have a few questions however regarding what will happen if the certificate at the ADFS end is updated (which may occur before we migrate) - if this happens

- will the existing user JWT's be invalidated ?
- I don't see anywhere where the thumbprint of the old (or potentially new) ADFS certificate is held - should it be registered somewhere ?
- as I understand it RSA keys don't expire - is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use AddDeveloperSigningCredential in production, because you might (depending on your setup) loose the key when you re-deploy and if that happens a new signing key is generated. That in turn will mean that all already issued tokens will be invalidated.

A better approach is to use the AddSigningCredential method and store the key outside IdentityServer.

When you do key-rotation, you can keep the old keys around for validating already issued tokens and you then use the AddValidationKey to add the reitred old signing keys.

see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/keys/

And yes, RSA-signing keys does not have any expire time, however, sometimes you  wrap and transport the RSA-key inside a certificate and then you have a date/time component added.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tore-Nestenius - the code I have was inherited - just to confirm though - the question of "if the certificate at the ADFS end is updated...will the existing user JWT's be invalidated ?" - do you have any insight if AddDeveloperSigningCredential is used

Comment: you use AddDeveloperSigningCredential locally in development, but you should try to avoid in production. You can actually have multiple signing keys in IdentityServer and you  can even per client control which key is used where. About ADFS I am not so sure. Usually you have your own key in IdentityServer and then if you support authentication of uses To ADFS via IdentityServer, then that does not change your local keys.